# How to flatten a fish eye picture (with python)?

Tags: python, image-processing, fisheye, photography

I've found programs to turn fish eye pictures into flat ones.

I'd like to learn the process behind the scenes.

Can someone share their knowledge about the technique?

Comment: Pyton is not the right kind of language to do image processing with.
Panotools could do it - command line based image processing.  Takes some time to get the hang of though.

Comment: Depending on the needs, python can also be a good image processing language using PIL(python imaging library)

Comment: Not sure if or how much you want to automate the process.  Also, are you looking to auto-detect edges in order to determine how much fish eye your photos have?  Were all the photos taken with the same lens?  Regardless, if you use PIL, you would probably waant to convert to a numpy array and perform your "rectilinear conversion/transformation" there.  Alternatively, paanotools look like they have python bindings

Comment: If PIL is not enough, `Scipy.ndimage` module can perform array-based image processing with a lot of sophistication.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that fish eye effect is basically a projection on a semi-sphere, right? To reverse that you need to use equations for projecting a semi-sphere into a plane. A quick search revealed those Fisheye Projection [equations](http://wiki.panotools.org/Fisheye_Projection), reversing them should be easy. I hope that puts you in the right direction.